# Typescript compiler error generic type with inheritance

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, typescript-typings

The following code fails to compile because of a typing error in the `output` variable:

> Type '{ item: ModelInterface; }' is not assignable to type
>   'ResponseInterface'.   Types of property 'item' are incompatible.
>       Type 'ModelInterface' is not assignable to type 'T'.

```typescript
interface ModelInterface {

}

interface ResponseInterface<T> {
    item: T;
}

class Store {
    get<T extends ModelInterface>(): ResponseInterface<T> {
        let output: ResponseInterface<T> = {
            item: this.getModel()
        };
        return output;
    }

    getModel(): ModelInterface {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `get` method explicitly define that `T` will always extend `ModelInterface`, why can't I set an explicit `ModelInterface` object into `item` without an error?

I can overcome this error by doing:

```typescript
let output: ResponseInterface<T> = {
    item: this.getModel() as T
};
```

But it looks like a bug, I am missing something or the typescript compiler simply fail on this case?

I've tried in on the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ModelInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ResponseInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Store%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%3CT%20extends%20ModelInterface%3E()%3A%20ResponseInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20output%3A%20ResponseInterface%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item%3A%20this.getModel()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20output%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09getModel()%3A%20ModelInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20null%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) but it fails too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `T` extends from `ModelInterface` does ensure that any `T` instance will be possible to "cast" to `ModelInterface`. But it does not mean otherwise.

For example:

```
class ModelInterface
{
    public name: string;
}

interface ResponseInterface<T> {
    item: T;
}

class ModelInterfaceExtended
{
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}

class Store
{
    get<T extends ModelInterface>(): ResponseInterface<T> {
        let output: ResponseInterface<T> = {
            item: this.getModel()
        };
        return output;
    }

    getModel(): ModelInterface {
        return null;
    }
}

const s = new Store();
let result = s.get<ModelInterfaceExtended>();
```

Here `result` will have property item of type `ModelInterfaceExtended` with properties `name` and `age`. Whereas `getModel` cannot create such objects as it return type is `ModelInterface` - with `name` only.

You can fix it by doing the following changes:

```
class ModelInterface
{
    public name: string;
}

interface ResponseInterface<T> {
    item: T;
}

class ModelInterfaceExtended
{
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
}

class Store<T extends ModelInterface>
{
    get(): ResponseInterface<T>
    {
        return {
            item: this.getModel()
        };
    }

    getModel(): T
    {
        return null;
    }
}

const s = new Store();
let result = s.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes perfect sense. In my real case however, things are not as simple as in the example. My base class for stores is defined as you did in your example but the method returning a `ModelInterface` is defined on the `ModelInterface` interface itself (method called `importValues` which returns a `ModelInterface` because its the only type it can know). But I now understand why the compiler returns an error and I thank you for that.